# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation " " does not exist when running pytest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I am experiencing a very funny bug in Django. I have gone every way possible including resetting migrations. I have written a pytest for a Django project however the above error occurs when running.

[image]
[image]

Accounts model

```py
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name='email', max_length=255)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='phone') 
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  id_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date joined")
  OTP = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=1010)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="last login")
  otpCreation = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_landlord = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = "email" 
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id_number','role']

  objects = AccountManager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.phone

  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin
  
  def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

Comment: Well, can you share one of your models?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem check, i have added to the question

Comment: You did set up the test database right? If the database is named `foo`, Django will test with `foo_test`.

Comment: yes, the test database is created, and I have observed that. What could be the reason I am experiencing this problem.

Comment: have you ran migrations on your app?

Comment: I have run migration, reset migrations and re-run migration. Nothing happened.

Comment: Have you manually modified any of the migration files? Changed the name or contents of any migration files (including dependencies) or deleted any migration files?

Comment: it's a project I am maintain. How can I solve the error, if it was edited?